# running java code form terminal getting error

Tags: java, shell, automation, continuous-integration, github-actions

I found some reference that says I can add `#!/usr/bin/java --source 12` at the beginning of the file and run the file directly from the terminal.
I am able to run using this on my local machine, however, when I tried the same on Github action I'm getting the error `error: invalid value for --source option: 12`

I'm not really an expert in shell scripting or java, can someone help me understand what this --source means is it the java version, I tried setting up the same version (jdk18) on Github action but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`java` (the runtime executable) can only run class files. Until, that is, java12, where a *normal* JDK distribution (and not the bizarro JREs that some packagers like Azul publish ^1) has a `java.exe` that *can* run java files straight up. It's simple sugar - the compiler is still involved, of course. It's just that `java` will execute it for you.

You don't need `--source 12`; just `java MySourceFile.java` is fine. Edit that comment at the top of your source file, it should just be `#!/usr/bin/java`. The thing you do need is that `java` on your command line `PATH` is a java v12 or higher, and **it is not**. There isn't anything your java source file can do about this, you're going to have to impose on your users to have at least java12 installed or this simply does not and can not be made to work. It looks like you're on some linux distro or other; `apt` or `yum` or `snap` or whatever package manager you have will tell you how to fix this: Install java17, and uninstall the rest or use `java-alternatives` or whatever mechanism your package manager has to set the default executable (the one `/usr/bin/java` links to). Read the documentation of the package supplying java17, possibly following some links to the generalized java infrastructure package, it should tell you.

Mostly this is a red herring, this just isn't how java files are distributed. It's virtually pointless because:

1. Java is not a language that tends to be used for quick shell script-esque things. Such things tend to be self-fulfilling prophecies: Because nobody does this, library authors aren't thinking about it when they develop their APIs and the users of their libraries won't file enhancement requests for this either. Because common libraries aren't convenient when used for quick off-the-cuff shell scripts, java isn't used for it, thus perpetuating the cycle.
2. Any serious java app would definitely involve packages, dependencies, and more - and such apps **cannot** be run like this.
3. Class files are as platform agnostic as source files are. There is no sane reason to distribute java-written shell-script-esque tooling as a source file instead of a jar, *except* for off-the-cuff editing off them, which gets you right back to point #1 and #4.
4. The java core APIs work on a model of lowest common denominator: If there is a major OS that cannot or doesn't work in a certain way, then java simply **does not expose this at all**. For example, on all posix systems (i.e. pretty much every major OS except windows), you have your usual TERM, KILL, HUP, etc signals. Java core libs don't let you interact with them (unless you dip into hidden `sun.misc.*` API which doesn't reliably work in the first place). This makes java extra unsuitable for quick command line scripting where you want a different model: If at least one OS can do it, the language should have a library for it, and that library should simply fast-crash if you attempt to use it on an OS that doesn't support it. One easy way around this is a third party library that adds support for OS-specific stuff, but your model of distribution (stick `#!/usr/bin/java` at the top and distribute a source file) **cannot** include dependencies.
5. Java as a runtime model is mostly focused on running things *eventually* very quickly, at the cost of *starting off* slowly. This is fantastic for web servers which need to run efficiently but will be running for quite some time. It's utterly unsuitable for shell scripting, though.

CONCLUSION: You don't want to stick `#!/usr/bin/java` at the top even if you could make it work.

[1] A JRE is a java distribution without compilers and other development tools like jstack. These cannot run `java SomeSourceFile.java`, obviously; they do not have a compiler. However, **JREs died** - there are no JREs anymore; JDK8 is the last one that shipped with an official JRE. The JRE serves as a distribution model: The end user installs a JRE, and you ship your jars to them. This model is obsolete (you are now responsible to get something that can run your class files on the deployment machine), and therefore JREs died. However, some packagers of OpenJDK builds, such as Azul, still publish them, confusing matters. Hence, 'bizarro'. Azul and co have relatively good reasons for doing it, but, you shouldn't be using these unless you really know what you are doing.